# How to reconfigure a Google App Engine Java project to work with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine (Java) project that worked happily for many years. Until the project format was changed to the Maven-based one. Now I can't upload a single file to my project without going through the hell of reconfiguring the whole thing to work under Maven. It could have been an easy process if it was documented properly.

I did find this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven

It first says: make sure you have Java installed. Okay, I have it installed of course, for about 15 years. And the very next step is: "Set the compiler flags in the pom.xml". The question is: WHICH pom.xml? Where do I find it? When I search, I can find dozens of pom.xml files, probably all of them under my Eclipse installation.

Is there some step-by-step guide explaining how to reconfigure an old Java Google App Engine project to work with Maven without assuming that I am already a Maven expert?

Comment: As a fellow greybeard I would strongly suggest you spend some time learning Maven.  It is old and grumpy and very opinionated, but it is close to the defacto build tool for Java these days.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you have provided, under the "[Creating a new project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#creating_a_new_project)" section, it says "inside the directory where you created the project, you'll have a subdirectory named myapp, which contains a pom.xml file". In addition to that, there is a visual diagram that helps you in locating the pom.xml file.

But most importantly, the link you have provided clearly states that it is **deprecated**. This means that you should not follow it since it is no longer supported and will probably not work.

You should instead follow this tutorial: [Using Apache Maven and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven).